# What is the name of the belief that acting ("the Will") is better than thinking?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

At certain points in history some authoritarian regimes have proposed [points of view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triumph_of_the_Will) that opposed individual rationalism.  (To give too much detail might invoke Godwin's law - but categorising that behaviour is becoming [more important](https://www.newstatesman.com/politics/media/2017/08/inventor-godwin-s-law-says-it-s-fine-call-charlottesville-rioters-nazis).)

An open minded point of view might say this is merely [behaviourism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behaviorism).

My question is: **What is the name of the belief that acting ("the Will") is better than thinking?**

Comment: Well, Bernard Shaw's character says  "*People who are able to do something well can do that thing for a living, while people who are not able to do anything that well make a living by teaching*", this sentiment is not specific to irrationalism or anti-individualism or behaviorism(???). That the Will is the root of all being is [Schopenhauer's philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Schopenhauer) but your phrasing is so strange I am not sure this is anywhere near what you want. "Better"? In what way?

Comment: I'm sorry, the correct name for what you describe appears to be voluntarism.   Nevertheless,  I think you will find it very helpful to know of Lukacs' use of vitalism. You might also find this book interesting:  Hans Kohn, "The Mind of Germany" (1960) free on Internet Archive. If you ever get to read Lukacs' Destruction of Reason, you can see an interesting, updated parallel in Habermas:  Title: The philosophical discourse of modernity : twelve lectures, Author Habermas, Jürgen.  Publisher:MIT Press,Pub date:c1987.

Comment: Kohn's book:  https://archive.org/details/mindofgermanythe002407mbp  As as practical matter, it's good to be aware of Karl Leuger, he has a Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gyorgy Lukacs would have probably used the name vitalism, but he tended to overburden this word I think.  See, "On Heidegger's Nazism & Philosophy" p. 149, by  Tom Rockmore; and G. Lukacs'  "Destruction of Reason". I would have never thought to mention behaviorism in a post such as yours, but I think it's brilliant.  One time I tried to read B.F Skinner's "Beyond Freedom & Dignity", and as I began to read between the lines it disturbed me so much I had to stop reading it. I became very suspicious of behaviorism after getting a little dose of Skinner.